# OpenCV Java - blank webcam capture

Tags: java, opencv, webcam

I have a strange problem while trying to get webcam capture in OpenCV using Java. I'm using Imshow() method from: https://github.com/master-atul/ImShow-Java-OpenCV and I'm using a slightly changed example code. The problem is: I get only the last frame while trying to capture, previous frames are blank, no matter how big is i variable in for loop.

In this example I should get 10 frames in 15 seconds but I get a single one after 15 seconds. Any idea what is wrong with this code?

If I'm using Highgui.imwrite() method I get 10 files in workspace folder.

```
public class WebcamThread extends Thread{

public WebcamThread() {
    capture();
}


private static void capture() {
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

    VideoCapture vcam = new VideoCapture(0);
    Imshow im = new Imshow("Camera capture in OpenCV");
    Mat m = new Mat();

    vcam.set(Highgui.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 800);
    vcam.set(Highgui.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 600); 

    // loop until VideoCamera is Available
    while (vcam.isOpened() == false);

    System.out.println("Found webcam: " + vcam.toString());

    // Bug Fix: Loop until initial image frames are empty
    while (m.empty()) {
        vcam.retrieve(m);
    }

    im.showImage(m);

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        vcam.retrieve(m);           

        System.out.println("Displaying " + i + " frame");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: In C++ at least to get anything to show one must add a `cv::waitKey()` call, as that function runs through the GUI event loop. Is there such a thing in the Java OpenCV? If so, perhaps try adding it.

Comment: Mine problem was a bit strange. The stranger thing is that code from: [this link](http://computervisionandjava.blogspot.com/2013/10/java-opencv-webcam.html) works fine on my laptop.